# C# UdpClient ReceiveAsync() performance issues

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, udp

I am troubleshooting performance issues in our Xamrin Forms C# application. I have found a fix that improves performance drastically, but do not fully understand the root cause. I would like to be certain that my fix is the best solution.

The original code was something like this (I have removed all code for handling received package):

```
public void Start()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(RunReceiveTask, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}

private async void RunReceiveTask()
{
    while (true)
    {
        UdpReceiveResult result = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
    }
}
```

As an attempt to improve the performance when receiving a big chunk of UDP packets the following changes were made in the RunReceiveTask(...) function:

```
private void RunReceiveTask()
{
    while (true)
    {
        IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        var receivedBytes = m_udpClient.Receive(ref remoteEndPoint);
    }
}
```

Basically the change involves using UdpClient.Receive(...) instead of **await** UdpClient.ReceiveAsync(...)

There is as far as I can see no issue with using the synchronous version in this case, but I would really like to understand why the performance is so much betters using the synchronous version!
I would also like to know if there are other ways I could have achieved the same performance improvements still using the async version.

I have been trying to figure this out and my initial thoughts is that the likely explanation is that there must be a lot of overhead calling await each time this the loop executes...

Does any C# gurus out there have any thoughts or ideas for me? :)

Comment: "improve the performance" is very vague statement. In this case what exactly improves, number of packets processed per second?

Comment: Sorry for the lacking explanation, but yes I am talking about number of packets processed per second.

Comment: It's hard to tell with provided code, but one reason might be the fact "async" version uses thread pool to execute code after await, and if in some other part of program heavy load is put on thread pool - that might lead to delaying execution of continuation after async. Second version runs on dedicated thread.

Comment: That sounds reasonable and was also my initial thought. Thanks for taking time looking into my question!